# Do I need to SQL escape parameters I pass to the Tridion broker?

Tags: tridion

I'm passing an SQL "like" query to the Tridion broker database, via the Query API:

```
var mkc = new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("Text");
var mvc = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(mkc, "%" + query + "%", Criteria.Like);
query.Criteria = mvc;
var results = query.ExecuteQuery();
```

The `query` variable is something that has been directly passed in by the user.

Do I need to try and SQL escape that parameter, or will Tridion handle this via parameterisation (or otherwise)?

Comment: Can you supply some more detailed information like what version of SDL Tridion you are using and what the problem is you are getting with this code (if any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDL products ***normally*** pass their parameters to the database in a structured way, so without string concatenation. This implies that you ***should*** not have to escape the criteria.

Did you try it? Does it work?